# How to get json of base64 from file list

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await, promise

I get file list and want to make json array like

```
[
  {"name":"IDCard001.jpg","base64":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA.."},
  {"name":"IDCard002.jpg","base64":"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AA.."},
]
```

My code:

```
  const getBase64 = (file: File) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
  };

  const handleFiles = (files: Array<File>) => {
    const list = files.map(async (file) => {
      return {
        name: file.name,
        base64: await getBase64(file),
      };
    });
  }
```

I can not use list as simple array. How Do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` method uses the return value of the function as it is [See map() in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The variable `list` will contain a list of Promises instead of the intended object.

You should wrap the map with `await Promise.all()` [See Promise.all()
in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and make the function async to have the objects array.

```
const handleFiles = async (files: Array<File>) => {
  const list = await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    return {
      name: file.name,
      base64: await getBase64(file),
    };
  }));
  return list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to be sure, but I think your issue is you are performing asyncronous operations within a map, so you need to ensure the promises resolve. I think this would solve your issue.

```
const handleFiles = async(files: Array<File>) => {
  const list = await Promise.all(files.map(async (file) => {
    return {
      name: file.name,
      base64: await getBase64(file),
    };
  }))
  console.log(list)
}
```